# Unable to lookup 'Time_From' on SubjectRoomSchedule or SubjectRoomSchedule

Tags: django

This is my first time encountered this error, idont know how to fix this, please help me...

my models.py

```
class SubjectRoomSchedule(models.Model):
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Classroom =models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Day_Name= models.ForeignKey(DayName, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Time_From= models.ForeignKey(TimeName, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Time_To= models.ForeignKey(TimeName, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Remarks = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)

class TimeName(models.Model):
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField()
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request,blank=True)
```

this is the traceback

[image]

UPDATE
admin.py

```
@admin.register(SubjectRoomSchedule)
class SubjectRoomSchedule(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Subject_Section_Teacher','Classroom','Day_Name','Time_From','Time_To','Remarks','Status')
    ordering = ('Subject_Section_Teacher','Day_Name',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either move your `TimeName` model above your `SubjectRoomSchedule` model or put quotation around your
`TimeName` model like this:

```
Time_From= models.ForeignKey('TimeName', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax I just copy your answer sir

Comment: @MaryRoseVillaganasOrcullo sorry i typed backticks instead of quotation.Try the updated answer

Comment: ive already tried that sir, but the error is still the same """"Unable to lookup 'Time_From' on SubjectRoomSchedule or SubjectRoomSchedule""""

Comment: @MaryRoseVillaganasOrcullo can you share your admin.py file also

Comment: I post my admin.py related to subjectroomschedule please see

Comment: I already solve my problem sir, thanks , i got my error because of ""Time_From="" i just put space """"Time_From ="""""